# Does whatsapp store password?? Or are their Sockets always open?

Tags: sockets, openfire, ejabberd, strophe

I am trying to figure out how to auto-reconnect a ejabberd socket connection. Like whatsapp, Facebookmessenger etc

For example, when the app is closed, and i receive a push notification to wake the app up and that calls to connect the connection, or if i put the app to the background for an hour, and the connection has been idle too long and get disconnected,then i put the app back to the foreground.
 I can only think of 2 ways to automatically connect to the ejabberd server.

1.) To have the JID and Password stored(but this is not good for safety reason)

2.) To have the ejabberd idle connection set to never disconnect a connection(But this uses quite a lot of resources)

Is there any other possibility to automatically re-connect a user to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stay connected all the time on mobile. This is the case today on iOS and is going to be the same on Android with Android Marshmallow.

So, you need to authenticate and store some form of credentials. It does not have to be a password. If you have a custom auth module in ejabberd for example, it can be a token.

Please, note that you can also store sensitive data encrypted on mobile. Both Apple and Google provide a keychain API that is design to protect the credential. It is not accessible in cleartext from a backup for example.

Comment: Cool, thanks i guess i will just have to encrypt the credentials, then when the device detect it is disconnected, i just call the connect function again with the credentials.

Comment: Why would this change with Marshmallow?

Comment: @Flow You should look into the new power management feature call App Standby. When device is not plugged and app is not used, it will not be allowed to get network access: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/power-mgmt.html